# What is the fastest way to get a Ethereum wallet client up and running?

Tags: wallets, gui

I usually run my coin wallets in a ubuntu virtual box for the fear of malware or trojans embedded into wallet clients. Coming from a vanilla ubuntu 14 install, what is the fastest way to get an ethereum wallet client up and running where I can check my balance and do other actions? A gui would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and most trustworthy wallet is the official [Mist](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases) wallet. It is still in beta, but it allows you to manage accounts, interact with contracts, and buy more ether (via [shapeshift](https://shapeshift.io)).

Simply download the release for your distribution and extract the binaries.